# Stuck in Ruby's IRB

Tags: ruby, irb

n00b query :: Okay so I'm messing around with Ruby's IRB, and it works (at least it appears to) but was wondering how to escape from its clutches without having to close and reopen the Windows Powershell. In short; clear the IRB to get back to the regular prompt.

Ruby v2.2.6p396

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `exit` and return or press `ctrl-D` on your keyboard.

Comment: Woot! TY sagarpandya82!! 

BTW, I'd vote up your response but I lack the rep.